# Alias in OGNL inside MyBatis

Tags: mybatis, ognl

I'm programming with MyBatis and I have this code

```
<if test="@mypackage.verylongname.utilities.MyBatisUtilities@isNotEmpty(recipient)">
    and DOCUMENTS.recipient = #{recipient}
</if>
```

I'd like to have a way to avoid to use the full pathname of my class MyBatisUtilities. Is it there?

Adding an Alias to the mybatis-config file doesn't work

```
<typeAlias alias="MyBatisUtilities" type="mypackage.verylongname.utilities.MyBatisUtilities"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think there is a way no, not unless mybatis provides some special extended functionality  for OGNL.

That doesn't mean it ~couldn't~ be done within OGNL somehow with changes to the core library, just don't believe it does currently. (my memory may be bad, but pretty certain @fullclassname@methodname is the only way OGNL knows of to resolve static method invocations)

Answer (score 0):

"bind" lets you make a variable out of an OGNL expression. For more info see : http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html

```
<select id="selectBlogsLike" parameterType="Blog" resultType="Blog">
    <bind name="pattern" value="'%' + _parameter.getTitle() + '%'" />
    SELECT * FROM BLOG
    WHERE title LIKE #{pattern}
 </select>
```